# What is the drink Deckard has in the bar (Blade Runner)?

Tags: blade-runner, blade-runner-series

In the movie, Deckard is shown to have a drink in a bar. The drink seemed to have worms under the glass. Is there a sci-fi explanation for that drink?

Comment: Deckard clearly doesn't drink enough to compensate for his misery.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [glass](http://collection.mybladerunner.com/margarita-glass/) is what you'd often see for a [margarita](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margarita) which is usually made with Tequila but can also be made with Mezcal to make a Mezcal Margarita, all of which were becoming very popular again in the [eighties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1980s).

[image]

Looking closely you can just about make out the sugar/salt on the rim.

Answer (score 7):

An earlier draft of the screenplay [(Feb 1981)](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/blade-runner_shooting.html) indicates that he's drinking Mezcal without ice, which he describes as a glass of "**[smokey](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/04/22/dining/22mezcal.html?_r=0)**, dry"

> **TAFFEY** (to the bartender) : *Louis, the man's dry.  Give him one on the house, huh ?*
>
> **BARTENDER :** *Whatcha drinking ?*
>
> **DECKARD :** ***Smokey, dry.***
>
> **TAFFEY :** *You assed about a snake.....*
>
> Deckard is suddenly hopeful.
>
> **DECKARD :**  *Yeah.....*
>
> **TAFFEY :** *Wanna see a snake, huh?*
>
> **The Bartender puts a weird drink in front of Deckard, tiny worms floating in a viscous liquid.**
>
> Deckard takes the drink like he was used to it and swigs.

Comment: Up until now I did not notice the worms at the bottom of his glass. I guess it's about time I re-watch the movie once more.

Comment: @Clockwork - I think you mean twice more. You'll need to watch it a second time with the commentary track turned on

Comment: I just realised there are 3 commentary versions in the Final Cut. That's... quite a lot of hours. All 3 combined would amount to practically 6 hours of movie time.

Comment: @Clockwork - You're also going to need to set aside time to watch the Director's Cut and the commentary that goes along with that

Answer (score 6):

I've not seen Blade Runner for a long time, but it could be a nod to Mezcal http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mezcal which can contain moth larvae.

Answer (score 5):

He drinks Mezcal at the Taffey Lewis' Bar.

For an interesting collection of information about Blade Runner drinks (and glasses) check this page: [http://www.brmovie.com/Collect/BR_Col_Glasses.htm](http://web.archive.org/web/20080302134649/http://www.brmovie.com/Collect/BR_Col_Glasses.htm)